# How can I call a method from a separate class that contains a randomized value and use that value to print in my main class?

Tags: java, class, random, methods, printing

I am new to coding and I am trying to figure out how to call a method from a separate class and use it in my main class. I know that it is easier to do it in the main class but I was asked to do it in a separate class. The random number that is printed to range from 1 to 3 but using this method I just get 0.

here's the main class:

```
package example;

public class Example {

    public static int number;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        otherClass a = new otherClass();
        a.assignNumber();
         System.out.println(number);
                 
         
    }
    
}
```

and my separate class:

```
package example;

import java.util.Random;

public class otherClass {
     public int assignNumber(){
        Random num = new Random();
        int number = num.nextInt(4) + 1;
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at your method, you will see that it returns something, so you task is to assign that the your declared variable `number` like `number = a.assignNumber();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value of `number` variable is 0 since its type is `int`. You need to assign the return value of function to `number` variable.

```
package example;

   public class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        otherClass a = new otherClass();
        int number = a.assignNumber();
        System.out.println(number);
                 
        // Or 
        System.out.println(a.assignNumber());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `number` variable in 'Example' class differs from the `number` in 'otherClass'.

The easiest way to fix your code is to fix the assignment part:

```
number = a.assignNumber();
```

But you should probably check your code again: It is better to use local int variable  instead of static field.

```
package example;

public class Example { 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        otherClass a = new otherClass();
        int number = a.assignNumber();
        System.out.println(number);
       
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real use for the `number` variable.

It can all be condensed to

```
package example;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         System.out.println(new otherClass().assignNumber());
    }
}
```